# Computed write not working for arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I have total calculation input boxes that are both readable and writeable.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:TotalCostQuantity">
     <input data-bind:"value: Cost, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" /><br />
     <input data-bind:"value: Quantity, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
```

My view model looks like this:

```
self.TrancheCostQuantity = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            //do some math here to calculate cost and quant totals

            return [{Cost:100, Quantity:10},{Cost:200, Quantity:20}];
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            customformat(newValue);
        }
    }, self);
```

The cost and quantity are from a grid that can have a dynamic number of rows and columns. It is mapped using the ko.mapping plugin.

I need the write to fire but it never does. The read works fine but I can't validate or custom format my writes.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle ?

Comment: What the `customformat` function does?

Comment: customformat will just make TrancheCostQuantity round up to the nearest dollar and add a dollar sign.

Comment: Please consider updating your question, and add more relevant code. Put yourself in our shoes to see that we need more information to be able to [reproduce](http://sscce.org/) this and help you. As mentioned by @Damien, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) may help (though the question in itself should make sense without it as well).

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You should be more careful when you post examples. Please make sure they work:

- In the HTML you have `TotalCostQuantity`, but in the viewmodel: `TrancheCostQuantity`
- In the HTML you use `data-bind:"value...`, but this should be `data-bind="value...`

The problem with the computed observable is that you change the contained values, but not the array itself when you edit the values, so the `write` function is never called. (This is besides the fact that even if knockoutjs worked this way, it wouldn't work because the `Cost` and `Quantity` properties aren't observables).

A working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Zqm/

```
var CostQuantity = function(cost, quantity) {
    self = this;

    self.Cost = ko.observable(cost);
    self.Quantity = ko.observable(quantity);

    self.CustomFormat = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseInt(this.Cost(),10) * parseInt(this.Quantity(),10);
    }, self);
};

var vm = function() {
    self = this;
    self.TotalCostQuantity = ko.computed(function() {
        //do some math here to calculate cost and quant totals

        return [new CostQuantity(100,10), new CostQuantity(200,20)];
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Comment: Yes! Excellent answer. Much like OP, I was over-complicating my code when the 'write' was never going to be triggered.